# What is rel="pingback", and what is the use of this in my website?

Tags: pingbacks

Maybe this is a silly question, I actually want to know what is this URL? It's present in [my website](http://www.orclage.com/).

`<link rel="pingback" href="http://www.example.com/xmlrpc.php" />`

My questions are:

1. What is the use of this?
2. Can this link cause any problems?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### It's "Pingback"

**What is Pingback?**

> Pingbacks (also known as trackbacks) are a form of automated comment for a page or post, created when another WordPress blog links to that page or post.
> When you publish a new blog post, WordPress attempts to ‘ping‘ all the sites that were linked to in your post. i.e. Your WordPress website is informing other websites that you’ve linked to them.
> When you receive pingpacks, then it means someone else has linked to one of your posts or pages. ([:source^](http://www.wpdoctors.co.uk/with-wordpress-whats-a-pingback-should-i-approve-them/)) (also learn more: [WordPress.com Support](http://en.support.wordpress.com/comments/pingbacks/), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pingback), and the [Codex glossary](http://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Pingback))

And a more details about Pingback and Trackback, look here:

> [**Codex: Pingbacks**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Introduction_to_Blogging#Pingbacks)

### Removing Pingback

To get rid of the pingback URL, just delete the line from your `header.php`:

```
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
```

The following article may help you understand, why:

> [**Minimizing HTTP Requests with WordPress Themes** - ClickNathan.com](http://clicknathan.com/web-design/minimizing-http-requests-with-wordpress-themes/)

### Answers

Now come to your questions:

> 1. What is the use of this?

**Answer:** If you read all the resources, you now understand what's the use of it.

> 2. Does this link makes any problems?

**Answer:** No, it's just make a new query to the database, if the pingback URL is not defined directly. If defined programmatically then it just query the database once every page load and retrieve the pingback URL from db. It's not good for a healthy site to ping database for less important things. And if you read the links, pingback is not important.

But till we can seek:

- [Trackbacks and Pingbacks: Positive (+)](http://dailypost.wordpress.com/2013/04/25/trackbacks-and-pingbacks/)
- [Trackbacks and Pingbacks: Negative (-)](http://piedtype.com/2013/05/21/spammers-use-trackbacks-pingbacks-and-reblogs/)

Comment: I’m not sure about your reasons. “Minimizing HTTP Requests” - this won’t make any difference: including a pingback URL won’t add an extra HTTP request for normal readers. “it’s just make a new query to the database” - no, bloginfo(‘pingback_url’) is computed from get_option(‘site_url’) which is autoload=yes and so read by wp_load_alloptions, and won’t require an extra database query.

Comment: @Rup Then it's a valid point to discuss on the Nathan's blog article... With your consensus I'll revise the answer anytime